# Is there a more graceful way to format a form in a table besides this? I have different number rows

Tags: html, css

In the first row, I have four columns. Rows 2-4 I have 2, to help with formatting. Is there a more graceful way to do this in order to avoid the validation warning?
This is just for a school project, nothing intense or anything, but I would like to get it right.

```
<div>
            <h2>Personal Information</h2>
            <form method="post">
                <table class = "center">
                    <tr>
                        <td style = "text-align:right;">First Name:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input name = "fname" type = "text"
                                size = "25" maxlength = "20"
                                required autofocus>
                        </td>

                        <td>Last Name:</td>
                        <td> 
                            <input name = "lname" type = "text"
                                size = "25" maxlength = "20">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Email Address:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input name = "email" type = "email"
                                placeholder = "e.g., JohnDoe@example.com"
                                size = "25"
                                required title = "Must be a valid email address">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style = "text-align:right;">Gender:</td>
                        <td style = "text-align:left">
                            <label>Male</label>
                                <input name = "gender" type = "radio"
                                    value = "Male">     
                            <label>Female</label>                   
                                <input name = "gender" type = "radio"
                                    value = "Female">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style = "text-align:right;">Age Group:</td>
                        <td style = "text-align:left">

                            <label>Under 21</label>
                                <input name = "under" type = "checkbox"
                                    value = "under">
                            <label>21 - 40</label>
                                <input name = "to" type = "checkbox"
                                    value = "to">
                            <label>Over 40</label>
                                <input name = "over" type = "checkbox"
                                    value = "over">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: What validation warning are you trying to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

for the rows you have only 2 columns you can use colspan to make a cell span multiple columns so everything lines up.

Ex:

```
<tr>
 <td>Email Address:</td>
 <td colspan="3">
  <input name = "email" type = "email" placeholder = "e.g., JohnDoe@example.com" size = "25" required title = "Must be a valid email address">
 </td>
</tr>
```